# reorder line segments in line layer so lines are continuous

Tags: qgis

I have a line layer (river network) that I need to set up stationing along the lines.  Some of the lines are composed of multiple line segments that are not ordered sequentially. Is there a way I can "re-flow" the lines so they are all continuous and in one direction using QGis?

I've tried dissolving and merging, but these do not fix the problem.

I can fix it by hand using

1. multiparts to singleparts
2. change symbology to arrow to display line direction
3. flipping individual segments
4. cleaning up any segments that don't connect
5. merging back to single parts.

But this is pretty tedious and isn't practical for a layer with hundreds of lines, many of which are erroneously composed of multiple segments, so I am looking for a process that can do it systematically.

Answer (score 0):

I think this approach could help, surely there is a better way, but for my case it works, but you have to do this process with each line.
In my case, I am working with a route layer (lines) and I need to put some points at a distance of 1 meter, which you will see later that this value will not remain exactly, but you can round it. The problem is that in the photo that I attached, the route "RP 39" is discontinued by "RP 2".

After trying different approaches, I selected this one:
First of all, select the different segments of RP 39 with the "**Join multiple lines**" plugin. This creates new parts to the line but you can remove them by cutting them.

[image]

But previously you have to check if the direction of the line is correct, for example with the "vertex tool". If it is not correct, you can use “**invert line**”.

I then use the "**Qchainage**" plugin, with the "force on last point" option in the basic parameters, to create a point at the end of each "segment". But each segment will always start at zero, so with the field calculator I have to update the next values of the following "segment" by adding them to the last point of the first segment.
The same is necessary to do when there will be another "segment".

I hope you understand what I'm saying. Any questions write me.

Comment: This sounds pretty similar to the manual process I was using. I was hoping for a process that automates selecting and inverting lines.